# Hook to shutdown method in Quartz.net

Tags: c#, quartz.net

I have a long running job that iterates over million of rows to do some tasks.
I want to be able to stop in the midle of this iteration if shutdown was requested for the job. Basically I have this

```
public class MyLongRunningJob : IJob
{   
    public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        var rows = GetAllRows();
        foreach(var row in rows)
        {
            DoSomething(row);
        }
    }
}
```

and I want something like this

```
public class MyLongRunningJob : IJob
{
    bool _stop = false;
    public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        var rows = GetAllRows();
        foreach(var row in rows)
        {
            if(_stop) break;
            DoSomething(row);
        }
    }
}
```

Since the Execute method can take more than 1 hour I would like to set _stop to true at somepoint, I cannot find anything on the IJob or Scheduler to hookup when I call Shutdown of my scheduler.

This long running job is the only thing executed on my windows service and want to exit from the Execute method ASAP.

The windows service is a TopShelf service with Autofac and looks like

```
public class Service : IService
{
    private readonly IScheduler _scheduler;

    public Service(IScheduler scheduler)
    {
        _scheduler = scheduler;
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        _scheduler.Start();
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        _scheduler.Shutdown();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use a cancellation token, or autoresetevent

Comment: thanks @CallumLinington for the suggestion, I can wrap any of those in a class, single instance with autofac, is a good idea, but I wanted something more direct with Quartz. I will give your idea a try if there is no other solution.

Comment: Have you seen this https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet/blob/master/src/Quartz/IInterruptableJob.cs

Comment: That's probably what I was looking for. Make your comment an answer, and I will accept this, and upvote. Thanks a lot @CallumLinington

Comment: I added the answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I was reading into Quartz. I've never used it before, but this thread was interesting [Async/Await Support](https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet/issues/248)

After reading down, I noticed the current idea is to use `IInterruptableJob` which inherit `IJob`.

This allows the schedular to call the interrupt method to allow you stop your code "nicely". From the docs on that interface:

> The means of actually interrupting the Job must be implemented within the
>    itself (the  method of this 
>   interface is simply a means for the scheduler to inform the 
>   that a request has been made for it to be interrupted). The mechanism that
>   your jobs use to interrupt themselves might vary between implementations.
>   However the principle idea in any implementation should be to have the
>   body of the job's  periodically check some flag to
>   see if an interruption has been requested, and if the flag is set, somehow
>   abort the performance of the rest of the job's work.  An example of 
>   interrupting a job can be found in the source for the class Example7's DumbInterruptableJob 
>   It is legal to use
>   some combination of  and  
>   synchronization within  and 
>   in order to have the  method block until the
>    signals that it has noticed the set flag.

I hope this helps.